# WooCommerce Checkout Fields - Select Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using [WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/checkout-field-editor/), I added a State Select list to the Additional Fields section. After reviewing the documentation, it looks like I can only specify the option value

```
Pipe (|) separate options
```

which generates

```
<option value="AL">AL</option>
<option value="AK">AK</option>
<option value="AZ">AZ</option>
```

I need to generate

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Arkansas</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Which plugin you are using ? Author ?

Comment: I am using [WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/) by WooCommerce. Thanks.